# app/console takes much longer to execute when connected to the internet

Tags: symfony, command

On my development machine I have a wierd behaviour: when I am not connected to the internet app/console commands execute instantly, but when I am connected to the net they take a long time (around one minute) before they start executing. Anybody has any idea why this might be?